# Binomial Distribution quesiton

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Paula moves to an area with different telephone exchange. Telephone numbers start with 753 and all combinations of the remaining 4 digits is equally likely.   What is the probability that the last 4 digits in Paula's new telephone number are odd?

I tried to do this, but it doesn't give me the answer:

I said n = 4
I honestly don't know what x is anymore..

p = 0.5 since there are 5 numbers that are odd through 0-9

q= 0.5 since there are 5 numbers that are odd through 0-9, maybe i got this part wrong?

Comment: $x$ will be how many of the numbers you want to be odd. For example, $P(X=3)$ would mean probability that 3 out of 4 numbers are odd.

Comment: @MattWatkins ok, I see. So would I make x 4 as well then? And would my p's and q's be right? because technically, there is an equal chance of getting odd and even

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you have it now. You have noticed that $X\sim$Binomial, or $X$ follows a binomial distribution. A known probability function for this is
$$P(X=x)=\binom{n}{x}p^xq^{n-x}.$$

$n=4$, for the four digits or "trials."

$p=0.5,$ because probability of getting an odd number is $\frac{5}{10}$ for each digit.

$q=1-p=0.5,$ since this is the probability of getting "not odd."

Then we try to find $P(X=4)$, which is the probability that all four digits are odd.